# how can I change this function in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

```
<script lang="js">
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  export default {
    setup(){
      const dateinput = ref(new Date())
      function dateSelected(payload : Date): void {
        console.log(payload);
      }
      return {dateinput,dateSelected}
    }
  }
</script>
```

I want to convert the above code to Composition API

```
<script setup>
import { ref} from "vue";
const dateinput = ref(new Date())
function dateSelected(payload : Date): void {
    console.log(payload);
}
</script>
```

I tried to write a function void in Composition API but couldn't!

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script setup>
//..
function dateSelected(payload) {
  console.log(payload);
}
</script>
```

> ##### In comparison, Vue Composition API:
>
> No need to manually cache callback functions to `avoid` unnecessary child updates. In general, Vue's fine-grained reactivity system ensures child components only update when they need to. Manual child-update optimizations are rarely a concern for Vue developers.

Comment: Thank you for your complete explanation and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

In the Composition API, the concept of "void" return type for functions is not explicitly used. In JavaScript, functions don't have an explicit return type, and you don't need to specify it in the setup function of Vue's Composition API.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const dateinput = ref(new Date());
function dateSelected(payload) {
 console.log(payload);
}
</script>
```

In the above code, you can simply remove the : Date part from the function parameter declaration because JavaScript is dynamically typed, and the type of the payload parameter will be inferred based on its usage.